# What does "programmatic contributors list" mean?

Tags: github, jenkins

I am setting up some example projects to see how continuous integration is set up with Jenkins. In my job configuration, I added the post-build action to "Set GitHub commit status (universal)". Under the "Where:" block, there is an option to choose which repositories to look for setting the build status. The default option is set to "Any defined in job repository," and the help text for the option says

> Any repository provided by the programmatic contributors list

My guess is that the statement means the Github plugin will use any repository defined the Source Code Management section of the job for posting build statuses, and that the plugin will post the build status for the commits used from each repository.

Is my understanding correct? What exactly does that statement mean, and what exactly does the Github plugin do based on that repositories option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code using that [help message](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=programmatic&type=) is [`jenkinsci/plugins/github/status/sources/AnyDefinedRepositorySource.java`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin/blob/93d40692ff3866705175624e93ec584d4ac88132/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/github/status/sources/AnyDefinedRepositorySource.java)

It includes comments like:

```
// Just uses contributors to get list of resolved repositories
// return all repositories which can be found by repo-contributors
```

It uses [`com/cloudbees/jenkins/GitHubRepositoryNameContributor.java`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin/blob/93d40692ff3866705175624e93ec584d4ac88132/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/jenkins/GitHubRepositoryNameContributor.java), which looks at the definition of Job and list up the related github repositories, then puts them into the collection.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I went on a wild goose chase looking for which classes extended GitHubRepositoryNameContributor, but I should have just scrolled down on the page showing its definition. So, as I expected, it seems like it just pulls the URLs from the source code management section.